# Is traveling from Uyuni (Bolivia) to San Pedro (Chile) easy?

Tags: chile, bolivia, salar-de-uyuni

Is traveling from Uyuni (Bolivia) to San Pedro (Chile) easy? I've read there are some problems on the border.

Also, should I wait to arrive in San Pedro before to buy a guide tour to see his sights, or should/can I buy such package in Uyuni?

Comment: I'll answer the first part, but the second part should be asked as a separate question - as per the [faq], one question per post is the policy on SE sites.

Comment: In addition, you really want to stop wording your questions subjectively - this one's not too bad as there's only one way really to cross the border, but the bit about asking whether to buy a tour - again, it's totally subjective - some people don't like town tours, others do.  You'll want to ask the question in a way that describes what YOU want to do - and then ask for the best way to go about it.  Subjective questions will generally get closed, as per the rules in the [faq].

Comment: It depends on what nationality you are. Most of the time the Chileans only make problems for Bolivians.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much will have to go on a tour.  It's through a national park area, and in addition to that, requires extensive knowledge of the area - there aren't many roads as such.  So you'll go on a tour, and they'll guide you through the border.

So in that regards, yes, it's very easy. You join a tour, and follow their instructions :)

I can recommend Tierra Mistica, although our guide only spoke Spanish, it was a very enjoyable trip (the tour at least, Uyuni didn't go so well for me, but that's a different story).

Comment: But, should I first arrive in San Pedro, or there are tours starting from Uyuni and ending up in San Pedro ?

Comment: Salt Flats tours from from Uyuni to San Pedro, San Pedro to Uyuni, or from one of those two to Tupiza, normally. So you'd get a tour from Uyuni to San Pedro, yes :)

Comment: Uyuni is a mixed bag. I had a good time but there are a lot of people who will try to take advantage of you there. Sometimes the service really stinks. I am a tour guide in Tarija.

Answer (score 2):

Tours on the Bolivian side are significantly cheaper.

On your own, it's easy to get from Uyuni to San Pedro, if a bit time consuming. Public buses run four times a week between Uyuni and Calama, take 7-9 hours, and run by day. In Calama, it's easy to get another bus to San Pedro.